# Woocommerce Tax Display

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i had modified a file a file in the /plugins/woocommerce/includes/ folder to change the way taxes are displayed in my cart and checkout.

i know its not good practice to do it like this, but before i could ask how to do it in the functions.php instead, woocommerce updated to 3.3.1 and my changes are gone.

What i am trying to achieve is to have a break before the "includes X tax" text, so its on two lines rather than one, and also to display text when there is no tax along the lines of "your order is tax free" with a hyperlink.

i got this to work by editing a file in the includes folder as i said above, but they seem to have changes the structure and i can;t find it anymore.

can anyone point me in the right direction or even better tell me how i can write this into the functions.php instead.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use hooks for this ))
I am sure that ouput in includes has a filter like this one

```
$output = apply_filters('tax_include_label', $label, $rate);
```

you can change label in your functions file by

```
add_filter('tax_include_label', function($label){
    return 'My lable' . $rate;
}, 10, 2);
```

See [hooks reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API). If you will give more information about your task i can help you.

Comment: i am already using this

add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_tax_or_vat', function () {
return __( 'GST', 'woocommerce' );
});

to change the word TAX to GST (Australia), but what i need is to add a break infront of the whole line, and when there are no tax, rather than no display at all, to say that the order is tax free.